# Eu tenho um método no ServerSide validaNIF e quero chama-lo através do javascript (ClientSide) para validar uma asp:textbox quando faz leave

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Tentei fazer através do evento ontextchange e chamar a função do backend, só que como isto é para fazer um registo, sempre que ele executava o evento limpa-me os dados das minhas outras textboxs(parece que faz refresh à página). Ficando só com os dados da textbox que eu estive a validar(nif).

```
public void validaNif(object sender, EventArgs e){

    .....

}
```

Comment: você precisa escrever um método e uma chamada Ajax

Comment: @PedroCardoso,  que tipo de validação e outras ações esse método deve fazer?

Comment: Ja pensou em fazer com Ajax? Se você estiver usando Submit com Post ele vai atualizar a página mesmo, A melhor maneira de fazer isso seria usando Ajax acredito eu

Comment: @RicardoPontual vou ver se me arranjo com Ajax (uso pouco)

Comment: @LeandroAngelo valida se o nif é valido através de um algoritmo ja desenhado pela autoridade tributaria. (posições de números , que tipo de números , length etc)

Comment: @EdenilsonBila A ideia é nao usar o Submit mesmo, mas sim quando fizer leave da text box (lostfocus) executar a minha função para validar a textbox. Vou tentar com ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui você tem dois pontos com soluções diferentes, se o seu problema é a impersistência dos dados após o postback de um controle, isso pode ser resolvido com o `ViewState`.

Agora, objetivamente sobre a pergunta de como executar um método do code-behind via Javascript, existe uma receita de bolo para isso, porém com uma aplicação mais restrita, seria necessário criar um método estático definido como `[WebMethod]`, que além ter uma configuração peculiar para o seu funcionamento, você não conseguirá manipular outros componentes ASP da sua página no lado do servidor.

Primeiro, verifique se na sua Site.Master, já existe um componente `<asp:ScriptManager>` declarado, caso a resposta seja sim, basta você adicionar o atributo `EnablePageMethods="true"`

```
<form runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
        <Scripts>
            //...
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <!-- resto do conteúdo -->
</form>
```

Feito isso, você pode adicionar o `[WebMethod]` estático para a validação no seu aspx. Uma vez que esse método não tem uma ligação com os componentes renderizados na tela, ao invés de um `void` `ValidarNif()` terá um retorno `bool` e receberá um parâmetro de entrada do tipo `string`.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static bool ValidaNif(string nif)
{
    //no lugar dessa linha você aplicará as suas regras
    return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nif);
}
```

Se tudo deu certo até aqui, ao renderizar a página e acessar o console do browser, você perceberá que existe um objeto `PegeMethods` inicializado, assim como uma representação do seu método com a seguinte assinatura `ValidaNif(nif, onSuccess, onFailure, userContext)`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode invocar esse método através do `PageMethods', lembrando de indicar o caminho base.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    PageMethods.set_path('/SuaPagina.aspx'); //Precisa ser definido apenas uma vez

    PageMethods.ValidaNif('teste', //Valor que você vai capturar do TextBox
                       onSuccess = function(res){alert(res);},
                       onFailure = function(res){alert('error:' + res);}
                      );
</script>
```

Caso você receba uma mensagem de erro com status `401 (Unauthorized)`, em seu projeto navegue App_Start e edite o arquivo `RouteConfig.cs` alterando o `AutoRedirectMode` para `Off`

```
public static class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
        //settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
    }
}
```

Comment: Leandro mas para eu usar o ViewState não tenho que fazer submit ? eu fiz no meu leave event ("valida nif" , que é executado ontextchange)  ViewState["nome"] = Request.Form["nome"]; só que ele faz a atribuição mas depois de sair do evento ele nao me entra no page load, será que tenho que acrescentar ao meu leave event um refresh page , ou um response.redirect para a mesma pagina ?

Comment: Para a solução com o `ViewState` é necessário um PostBack, mas aí seria uma outra pergunta dentro do mesmo cenário, "Como manter o estado de meus controles após o postback de um componente?"

Comment: Sim, acho que sendo assim escuso de estar a chamar funções com o javascript visto que o que quero mesmo é só guardar os dados da textboxs depois da execução do validaNif

Comment: Então... é que na verdade o meu post é a resposta para a sua pergunta... mas não a solução para o seu problema :P

Comment: Exacto xD Mesmo assim resolvi com o meu problema com a sua dica . ViewState já descobri como usar ja está funcional , se alguém precisar diga que eu posto a solução muito obrigado Leandro

Comment: Deixo ai o link com a solução para quem precisar https://asp.net-tutorials.com/state/viewstate/